# How to “select * from table from database” with -e?

Tags: mysql

I want to select and show 1 row form a table with the `mysql -e`.

I was trying out the following but no luck,

```
mysql -u root -e “select * from table1 from db01 limit 1”
```

Actually I am trying to dump a single line from hundreads of tables to take a sample from them and redirect to a file. So I want to use shell and don’t want to be in MySQL console.

I have used `show` the above way but `select` is not working.

Everyone is suggesting to do `select * from table1` but didn’t mentioned how to mention database. 
So how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

Just had to add the database name before the execute flag (`-e`) and the `sql` statement.,

```
mysql -u root db01 -e “select * from table1 limit 1”
```

Where,

- `db01` is the database name
- `table1` is the table name
- `limit 1` for showing only 1 record

Answer (score 0):

You have to from in your Select use only one
Like in my post

use out file like

```
mysql -u root -e “select * from db01.table1 limit 1” > /tmp/output
```

Which looks like

```
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|      471 | 
+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks but I had no issue redirecting the output, but I couldn’t use db01 inside sql statement as it returned error.

Comment: you wrote **from table1 from db01  **  that one From and table too much write db01.table1 instead